# What API I need to use in my case with TapKey integration?

Tags: tapkey

I have a few questions regarding Tapkey integration into our marketplace.

1. How to get a list of his locksmiths deposited at Tapkey? What API need to use?
2. I need to send the Id of the lock to Tapkey. What endpoint do I need to us for this?

Comment: Artem,
Ad 1) Not sure, what you mean by that. Did you check https://developers.tapkey.io/openapi/tapkey_management_api_v1/?
Ad 2) What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: We have a marketplace. Need to integrate the Tapkey locks sharing between customers and providers. When customers book some apartments for instance the marketplace should provide the access to the specific lock for the specified booked period.
We need to understand what of endpoints and API we need to use? We see a few options, but it's not clear enough.

Comment: As Markus already pointed out, please have a look on our Management API. This API is free to use and in my opinion well documented. It's important to get familiar with Tapkey ecosystem first e.g. by trying it our yourself and then it should be more clear what endpoints to use.  Unfortunately, Stackoverflow is meant to work as technical support for specific questions about implementation and not a guideline to entire implementation.  So please try to read it again and if there are any things that are not  clear let us know.

Comment: Hey there,

So our specific question is the next:
We have a Tapkey account, we created Client oAuth and gave him the Administrator role. We use the client's credentials for authorization. We need to get the list of the client's locks. How can we do this?